# How to reference the value the structure in a structure?

Tags: c

I am trying to print some values in struct..
But there are some problem, because that value are used in the structure of a structure.
How can I reference the value the structure in a structure ?
Thank you for your help ;)

```
struct a {
  int a1;   <=====???
  int a2;
};
struct b {
  int a *b1;
  int b2;
};

struct b *data;
printf ("The value of a1 is %d\n", ???? );
```

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't have an instance of `struct a`, so there is nothing to access.  Normally it would be `instance.member` or `instancePointer->member` - and I think you mean `%d` not `&d`

Comment: I have no idea about your question,because I could't understand your code.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot ; in structure a and %d is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a `;` in the `a` struct.

When declaring a variable of type `a` inside the `b` structure, you're doing it wrong. It should be:

```
struct b {
    struct a b1;
    int b2;
};
```

I'll just declare it as a struct type, and not a pointer to a struct, so you don't have to allocate memory.

And if you're really trying to compile this code, you surely need an entry point:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct b data;
    printf("The value of a1 is %d\n", data.b1.a1);
    return 0;
}
```

And as you can see, I declared a `b` struct inside `main`, named `data`. Now you can just access its members, and the members of its members, just by using `.`. And if it was a pointer (and it is correctly allocated), then you can use `->` instead of `.`.

Another thing I noticed is that you misspelled `%d` in the [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) call.

And you also need to include the standard I/O header to use `printf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

I really hope this code is just a poorly and fast written piece of code, because it is in no way compilable without a *major* modification.